# Getting connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm using POST method to insert some data to db on my server.This is my connection.php file that is stored in my http://www.url.com/public_html.

```
    <?php

$servername = "http://www.url.com";
$username = "db_username";
$password = "db_password";
$databaseName = "db_name";

$connect = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$databaseName);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

This is insert.php file also stored in http://www.url.com/public_html that I use to insert data in database.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require'connection.php';
    createStudent();
}
function createStudent(){
    
    global $connect;
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    
    $query="INSERT INTO  `demo` (  `name` ,  `lastname` ,  `age` ) 
    VALUES ('$name','$lastname','$age')";
    mysqli_query($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

I use postman, and my Android app to test this but I'm getting:
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known error.

Comment: If your database is on the same machine, use `$servername = "localhost"`.

Comment: It's because you can't resolve the host name Maybe DNS problems, host is unreachable...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My database is on the same machine so I just needed to edit:

```
$servername = "localhost"
```

Now everything is working just fine.

Answer (score 7):

The value you've specified for `$servername` is not a host name but rather a URL, or resource name. The host name would be just `www.url.com`.

Of course, as you've already discovered, `localhost` is the correct host name if the client and server reside on the same box.

Answer (score 2):

*For people coming from Google:*
If you work with Docker, you might use the name of the database docker container here, like

```
$dbserver='mydockerbox-mysql';
```

if your `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
services:
  mydockerbox-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    container_name: mydockerbox-mysql
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. If you are using docker, just use the name of the database container_name and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in bellow file `config-db.php`

```
nano  /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
```

change db server as localhost

```
$dbserver='localhost';
```

Its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

And to save time for anybody who made the same mistake as me - this is the error one gets if one creates a file of credentials on Windows and copies it to Linux.
It is easier to create the file in Linux.