# Connecting to multiple databases on different servers

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to connect to localhost and a remote server at the same time.
The goal is to synchronize data on the two servers, as an INSERT is being
done on the local server,it is also being done on a similar table on the remote server.

The remote server is given by an ip address, lets's call it "12.345.678.999" .

In my database config file, I have something like this:

```
<?php

// for local server

$DB_NAME = 'dbname1'; 
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'dbuser1'; 
$DB_PASS = 'dbpass1';  

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Database connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// for remote server

$DB_NAME2 = 'dbname2'; 
$DB_HOST2 = '12.345.678.999';
$DB_USER2 = 'dbuser2'; 
$DB_PASS2 = 'dbpass2';


$mysqli2 = new mysqli($DB_HOST2, $DB_USER2, $DB_PASS2, $DB_NAME2);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Database connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}


?>
```

So I have two different mysqli objects to use in my scripts to run queries for local and remote server.

On loading the local site, I get the following error :

> Database connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known

What is the proper way to achieve my objective of connecting to two servers at the same time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266567/getting-connection-failed-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or

Comment: `12.345.678.999` is not a valid IP address...

Comment: @PeterAbolins I'm pretty sure it's an example ip ...

Answer (score 0):

This looks an improper way to do this. You should create the [Replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) between this two servers.

If you insert data in Master server, It will automatically be reflected in the slave.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the DB Server cannot be found. This either means that the IP-address (the real one you are using for the remote server) is incorrect, or that the DB configuration files on the remote server are not correct. I am guessing, but if the IP-Address is correct, then have a look at:

```
remote_server://application/config/database.php
```

Ensure that the server is specified as 'localhost' rather than something else.